# Passing Jade partials with locals

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I wish to pass Jade includes with local variables coming from the controller. My data is simplified for this example, of course I'm looking to achieve something more complicated.

i.e

controller:

```
res.render("index", {title: "Lovely"})
```

index.jade:

```
section
  include list, {listTitle: title}
```

list.jade:

```
h3 #{listTitle}
```

but `listTitle` is not passed to the `include`,

In Rails we do this by assigning locals to partials , how can this be achieved in Jade?

Comment: Here is working example
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20343333/555938

Answer (score 1):

In Jade, partials are called mixins. For instance:

controller:

```
res.render("index", {title: "Lovely"})
```

index.jade:

```
include mixins

section
  +list(title)
```

mixins.jade:

```
mixin list(listTitle)
  h3 #{listTitle}
```

The mixin is defined in mixins.jade. It is then added to index.jade by using the + sign.

Answer (score 0):

***Controller:***

```
var listTitle = [{ title: 'foo' }, { title: 'baz' }];  
var title = "Lovely";
res.render("index", {title: title, listTitle: listTitle})
```

***index.jade:***

```
section
    for lists in listTitle
        include list
```

***list.jade:***

```
h3 #{lists.title}
```

Comment: That is ridiculous. Just use `title` in the `list.jade` and forget about `listTitle`.

Comment: As I mentioned, my code is a simplified example. What I really want to do is use `include` in a loop and pass it different parameters each time, like a partial in Rails