# Passing variables through Jade templates

Tags: pug

Is it possible in Jade/Pug to pass variables from one template to another? I want to do something like this:

**tmp1.jade**

```
div.anyClass
  include components/checkbox('someLabel')
```

**tmp2.jade**

```
div.otherClass
  div.label
    {someLabel}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Included templates inherit the variables scope of the template that included them, so what you're after will happen automatically for you.

So the following will work:

**tmp1.jade**

```
- var label = 'value'
div.anyClass
    include tmp2
```

**tmp2.jade**

```
div.otherClass
    div.label
        #{label}
```

You can also use mixins to pass variables, they are like functions (you define them first, then call them)

So you could do the following:

**tmp1.jade**

```
mixin labeldiv(myLabel)
    div.otherClass
        div.label
            #{myLabel}

div.anyClass
    +labelDiv("the label")
```

It's worth mentioning that you can also put mixins inside includes, if you want them to be common across multiple templates. You could do this:

**myMixins.jade**

```
mixin labeldiv(myLabel)
    div.otherClass
        div.label
            #{myLabel}
```

**tmp1.jade**

```
include myMixins
div.anyClass
    +labelDiv("the label")
```

The [Jade Syntax Docs](http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/) have some great (live) examples of how it all works.