# How to read in an API key with pug template engine?

Tags: pug

I have index.pug and it has some JavaScript in it to access the Google Maps APIs.  How do I read the API key in from an external file with pug?

// Add a map
   script(async='', defer='', src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
   key=api_key_goes_here&callback=initMap', type='text/javascript')

Comment: What have you tried so far? Questions on SO should demonstrate that the asker has attempted to solve the problem on their own before asking for help.

Comment: Thanks for the help sean!  Appreciate your guidance and helpfulness to help me resolve this issue!  Very much appreciated, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20343333/8380606

So the following will work:

tmp1.jade

```
- var label = 'value'
div.anyClass
    include tmp2
```

tmp2.jade

```
div.otherClass
    div.label
        #{label}
```

You can also use mixins to pass variables, they are like functions (you define them first, then call them)

So you could do the following:

tmp1.jade

```
mixin labeldiv(myLabel)
    div.otherClass
        div.label
            #{myLabel}

div.anyClass
    +labelDiv("the label")
```

It's worth mentioning that you can also put mixins inside includes, if you want them to be common across multiple templates. You could do this:

myMixins.jade

```
mixin labeldiv(myLabel)
    div.otherClass
        div.label
            #{myLabel}
```

tmp1.jade

```
include myMixins
div.anyClass
    +labelDiv("the label")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.