# Pass variable from parent to child PUG template?

Tags: pug

Seems a duplicate question. But I'm not getting how to do it.

I have templates as shown below.

**Index.pug**

```
block head
    title INCX - Exchange
block main
    include templates/_header
```

**dashboard.pug**

```
block head
    title INCX - Exchange
block main
    include templates/_header
```

**_header.pug**

```
header.header
    section.header-nav-section.full-width
```

Now, I want to pass a variable from **index.pug** and **dashboard.pug** to **_header.pug** to add a class to **header** element.

I tried as below

**Index.pug**

```
- var headerClass = 'index-header';
block head
    title INCX - Exchange
block main
    include templates/_header
```

**dashboard.pug**

```
- var headerClass = 'dashboard-header';
block head
    title INCX - Exchange
block main
    include templates/_header
```

**_header.pug**

```
- var headerClass = headerClass || "xyz";
header.header(class=headerClass)
    section.header-nav-section.full-width
```

But I'm getting following error

> Only named blocks and mixins can appear at the top level of an
>   extending template

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588691/passing-variables-through-jade-templates This answer is well explained and refers to your problem as well. https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html#default-arguments-values for adding default value for your mixin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing variables through Jade templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588691/passing-variables-through-jade-templates)

Answer (score -1):

This question technically isn't answerable because Pug (like every other template engine I've seen) doesn't have features for cross-component communication, so what you're asking for just doesn't exist.  IMO that would add a layer of complexity that would hurt both development time and rendering speed, which are the two main reasons people use Pug.

The solution to your issue is to pass variables from the route to the template, not from template to template.

All of the templates you bring together (using either extends, includes or mixins) become an aggregated single JavaScript in-memory rendering function, and that aggregated function takes all of its variables from the route that call it using `res.render`.  If you pass a variable using the route, every component template in your aggregated template will see that variable.

So given that, no you will not be able to declare a variable above a block, as blocks weren't designed to host their own variables. In other words, these are completely invalid pug templates and there's nothing you can do to "fix" it:

```
- var headerClass = 'index-header';
block head
```

and

```
- var headerClass = 'dashboard-header';
block head
```

You should probably create a new question that explains WHY you want to do this and the community can help you solve that issue.